# how to check php variable has datetime value?

Tags: php

I have a php variable which contain date-time value like `2014-05-11 23:10:11` some times this may change, so i have to find it either it has date-time value or not, below is my variable

```
$my-variable='2014-08-26 18:25:47';
```

Comment: You should change `$my-variable` to `$my_variable` in the code

Comment: it's just for an example

Comment: `$my-variable` can not be a name. It is `$my` minus `variable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you to check if the string is a valid date time in your format:

```
<?php

    $date = '2014-08-26 18:25:47';


    function isTime($time) {
        if (preg_match("/^([1-2][0-3]|[01]?[1-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$/", $time))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    $parts = explode(" ", $date);
    list($y, $m, $d) = explode("-", $parts[0]);

    if(checkdate($m, $d, $y) && isTime($parts[1]) ){
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo "BAD";
    }

?>
```

output:

```
OK
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is a class in PHP. You should ask a different question if you want to validate a string. To validate a `DateTime` instance:

```
$my_variable instanceof DateTime
```

Comment: not working, i have done this code `$my='2014-08-26 18:25:47';

$hai=strtotime($my);

if ($hai instanceof DateTime) {
  echo "its datetime";
}
`

Comment: @AshokSri no using `strtotime()` is not gonna make it a datetime object, its supposed to be `$hai = new DateTime($my)`. and you should put it inside a try and catch block to see exceptions

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_variable='2014-08-26 18:25:47';
...
if ($my_variable instanceof DateTime) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
if (is_a($my_variable, 'DateTime')) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string representing a date in time, you can use date_parse: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php  That will return an associative array with the parts of the date and time string if valid, FALSE if not.

If it's a date-time object, see the answer describing `instanceOf`.